# Spring component scan does not work for a packages with similar names within a jar

Tags: java, spring, jar, component-scan

I am running a component scan on a jar where I load a few packages. The package
    com.path.package works fine and is getting loaded but then beans within com.path.package.addon is not getting loaded in by the component scan

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.path.package, com.path.package.addon />
```

I did look at several questions before asking this one. None of them seem to give the answer to the problem I am seeing. There are no errors on my logs, when I try to get this bean from applicationContext, I just get the error bean not found. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to leave only "com.path.package"? It should work on all subpackages (so also on "com.path.package.addon"). If it won't work problem is something else.

Comment: Yeah you were right about the problem being something else. I tried to specify a bean in the appContext with the class I wanted as a bean and lo and behold the error showed up on the log. It was because the jar did not have several dependency packages as part of the export. So I create a osgi Service at this point of one of the beans and referenced it in the other project that I wanted the bean to be used on. There were several other beans that I needed from the jar file but this one has several dependencies.

Comment: Strange. How about `base-package="com.path.package.*`? Check if `com.path.package.addon` is really in your class path and the beans you want to load are correctly annotated. Good luck.